# React createElement error "type is invalid -- expected a string got object"

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

I have facing this problem in a react project. I am using rc-upload package for uploading files in react. code is as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
const Upload = require('rc-upload');

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.uploaderProps = {
    action: '/upload/',
    data: { user_id: 1 },
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer abcdef`,
    },
    multiple: false,
    beforeUpload(file) {
      console.log(file);
    },
    onStart: (file) => {
      // console.log('onStart', file.name);
    },
    onSuccess(result) {
      console.log(result);
    },
    onProgress(step, file) {
      console.log('Progress: ', Math.round(step.percent), file.name);
    },
    onError(err) {
      // Show response data with close button in modal body
      console.log('onError', err);
    }
  };
 }
 render() {

  return (
   <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
    </div>
    <p className="App-intro">
      To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
    </p>
    <Upload {...this.uploaderProps}>Choose File</Upload>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
export default App;
```

This code is working in react@15.5.4 and react-scripts@0.9.5 and the dev dependencies of react or react-scripts. I created react app through create-react-app few months before. And now I created new app with create-react-app which installed with react@15.6.1 and react-scripts@1.0.12.

So when I run the above code in new project than it is showing this error.

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object

I figure out that it is coming from below code:

```
<Upload {...this.uploaderProps}>Choose File</Upload>
```

And it is working in my previous version of react@15.5.4 but not in react@15.6.1

How to resolve this error? Is this a version error or any other dependency error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is related to how Upload component imported to the project. This might be a bug for the component. Don't know if this is intended or not but you need to import the component like this;

```
const Upload = require('rc-upload').default;
// or
import Upload from 'rc-upload';
```

Comment: Yes you are right. It is issue about import and after doing this my issue is resolved. Thanks @Bunyamin